# Кнопки у телеграм-бота

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Начал понемногу осваивать ботов в телеграме. Знаю немного Java. Сейчас работает бот, который через switch проходит по нужным ответам и выдает то, что ему задано.
Добавил 4 кнопки: команда 1, команда 2, команда 3 и команда 4. Они выполняют свою функцию. При любом ответе эти поля остаются, а хотелось бы, чтобы они менялись. Допустим, пользователь выбрал кнопку "Команда 1", а ему в ответ предложили 2 варианта вопроса, например "команда 1-1", "команда 1-2", команда "3-1" etc.

Код:

```java
    import org.omg.CORBA.PUBLIC_MEMBER;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardMarkup;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardRow;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Message;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
    import java.security.Key;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class SimpleBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApiContextInitializer.init();
            TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
            try {
                telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new SimpleBot());
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getBotUsername() {
            return "botname";
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getBotToken() {
            return "bottoken";
        }
    
        public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
            Message message = update.getMessage();
            if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
                switch (message.getText()) {
                    case "/start":
                        sendMsg(message, "Это команда старт!");
                        System.out.println(message.getText());
                        break;
                    case "Команда 1":
                        sendMsg(message, "Это команда 1");
                        System.out.println(message.getText());
                        break;
                    case "Команда 2":
                        sendMsg(message, "Это команда 2");
                        System.out.println(message.getText());
                        break;
                    default:
                        sendMsg(message, "Это дефолт! Брейк!");
                        System.out.println(message.getText());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void sendMsg (Message message, String text) {
            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
            sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    
            // Создаем клавиатуру
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new 
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboard(false);
    
            // Создаем список строк клавиатуры
            List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    
            // Первая строчка клавиатуры
            KeyboardRow keyboardFirstRow = new KeyboardRow();
            // Добавляем кнопки в первую строчку клавиатуры
            keyboardFirstRow.add("Команда 1");
            keyboardFirstRow.add("Команда 2");
    
            // Вторая строчка клавиатуры
            KeyboardRow keyboardSecondRow = new KeyboardRow();
            // Добавляем кнопки во вторую строчку клавиатуры
            keyboardSecondRow.add("Команда 3");
            keyboardSecondRow.add("Команда 4");
    
            // Добавляем все строчки клавиатуры в список
            keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
            keyboard.add(keyboardSecondRow);
            // и устанавливаем этот список нашей клавиатуре
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    
            sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
            sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
            sendMessage.setText(text);
            try {
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Как на счет использования что-то на подобие TreeSet?

Comment: @bench_doos вместо switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ был найден методом проб и ошибок.
1) Ставим в методе sendMsg на параметре replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboard - (true);
2) На каждый case создаем отдельный метод. На команду 1 - sendMsgcom1 с однима набором кнопок, на команду 2 - sensMsg2 с другим набором кнопок.